# how to tell jenkins to restart tomcat after deployment?

Tags: maven, jenkins

unfortunately I am new to jenkins and linux and hope somebody can help me here.

It is about the automatic build for our system. We use jenkins job to updatethe web system. after updating, tomcat and the system shoud be restarted. For updating the system we use the following execution command:

```
bash -l distr/deploy.sh -s /distr -a /data/mySystem -c /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.5 2>&1 | tee log.log
```

how to tell jenkins to start tomcat after deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial is for Tomcat 7, but the idea should be similar for v8: http://www.jdev.it/deploying-your-war-file-from-jenkins-to-tomcat/